# Graphql error after pulling new udates from Github repo on a project

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

In my React app which uses GraphQL and Apollo, I did a pull from a repo I'm working on with a team. After I did the migration to have last DB updates I started receive an error as shared below.
I would like to know what I need to do as per my team seems is an issue on my side like something did not updated correctly from a last pull of the project.

The fields the error refers are implemented in the project and used.
The query is shared also

I would like to know what other steps I may do to understand why this error happening and if can be any cache issue or else I need to reset.

```
{
   "errors":[
      {
         "message":"Cannot query field \"updatedAt\" on type \"Study\". Did you mean \"createdAt\"?",
         "locations":[
            {
               "line":10,
               "column":5
            }
         ],
         "extensions":{
            "code":"GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
            "exception":{
               "stacktrace":[
                  "Cannot query field \"updatedAt\" on type \"Study\". Did you mean \"createdAt\"?",
                  "",
                  "GraphQL request (10:5)",
                  " 9:     createdAt",
                  "10:     updatedAt",
                  "        ^",
                  "11:     archivedAt",
                  "",
                  "    at Object.Field (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectType.js:64:31)",
                  "    at Object.enter (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:334:29)",
                  "    at Object.enter (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:385:25)",
                  "    at visit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:252:26)",
                  "    at Object.validate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:63:22)",
                  "    at validate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:293:22)",
                  "    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:198:30)",
                  "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
                  "    at fulfilled (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:4:58)",
                  "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "message":"Cannot query field \"archivedAt\" on type \"Study\". Did you mean \"createdAt\"?",
         "locations":[
            {
               "line":11,
               "column":5
            }
         ],
         "extensions":{
            "code":"GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
            "exception":{
               "stacktrace":[
                  "Cannot query field \"archivedAt\" on type \"Study\". Did you mean \"createdAt\"?",
                  "",
                  "GraphQL request (11:5)",
                  "10:     updatedAt",
                  "11:     archivedAt",
                  "        ^",
                  "12:     selfAssessmentOptions {",
                  "",
                  "    at Object.Field (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectType.js:64:31)",
                  "    at Object.enter (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:334:29)",
                  "    at Object.enter (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:385:25)",
                  "    at visit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:252:26)",
                  "    at Object.validate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:63:22)",
                  "    at validate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:293:22)",
                  "    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:198:30)",
                  "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
                  "    at fulfilled (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:4:58)",
                  "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Query where the error happens

```
export const getStudy = gql`
  query getStudy($studyId: ID!) {
    study(id: $studyId) {
      id
      duration
      status
      internalStudyName
      startDate
      sponsor
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      archivedAt
      selfAssessmentOptions {
        welcomeImage
        colorMain
        colorLight
        fontInclude
        fontFamily
        messages
        contactForm
      }
      featureOptions {
        studyId
        recruitmentPortal
        engagementPortal
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: It looks like it cannot find two fields in of the schema - updatedAt and archivedAt. Perhaps they were removed, or the back end was changed to don't expose them?

Comment: Indeed, first guess would be that `archivedAt` field was removed from the structure returned by `study` query, however you mention that the field is still in place.

I would start the investigation by looking at the schema of `study` query using public endpoint and graphql exporer - to verify what is does it actually return. Maybe it's different type. Maybe you will notice that for some reason this field is not present - so some cache might cause it.

Comment: I see but why everyone have no issues and me yes? I already switched to master and have same issue after migrations and update code to last version

Comment: I discovered that 3 fields were added new actually but still  do not understand why I have issues as I updated the code. There is a way of reset cache? the system uses also RabbitMq maybe that the issue?